# Abrir video con window.open y obtener src del reproductor del video html5

Tags: javascript

Tengo una `URL` de un vídeo (no es de youtube) que quiero ejecutar desde `window.open`, al ejecutarse se carga automáticamente el reproductor de vídeo `HTML5` del navegador. La `URL` que tengo al ser leída por el navegador cambia, no es la misma.

Mi dilema, es que necesito obtener la `URL` de la  ventana `(window.open)` o el `SRC` del reproductor que se ejecuta en dicha ventana, "no necesito modificar ni remover", solo obtener el atributo `"src"` del reproductor cargado y obtener la `URL`, solo eso,  solo obtener la `URL` y que se almacene en una variable o en algún resultado mostrado como en un `.innerHTML` o que cargue un `iframe` con la `URL` ya procesada y luego el pop o la ventana se cierre.

Url_del_video = https://goo_gl-3WBWi4 (cambiar _ por . "punto" y - por /)

Nota: También me serviría alguna otra manera de obtener la URL **después de ser procesada**, acepto sugerencias y/o propuestas.

El codigo con el que e estado intentando inutilmente es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
 var myWindow = window.open("Url_del_video", "", "width=400,height=200");

var x = myWindow.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].getAttribute("src");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myWindow.x;
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].setAttribute('src',x);
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<iframe></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Una vez mas, esperando pronta respuesta y muchas gracias.

Comment: La `URL` será siempre acortada por `google` ?  podría emplear la misma `API`  para obtener la `URL` normal

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería emplear la [API de Google](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) que sí le pasa como parámetro la `URL` acortada  le retornará el valor de la `URL` completa *(longUrl)* o viceversa.

Haciendo un llamada tipo `GET` *(Jquery por simplicidad)*

```
<iframe id="mivideo"></iframe>

var url = "...";
$.get('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?',
     { shortUrl:  url , key : 'mikeygoogle'}, function(data) {
    $('#mivideo').attr('src', data.longUrl); // añadimos al iframe
});
```

> En `mikeygoogle` , debe añadir su `KEY` que le proporciona Google al activar la `API` `url-shortener`

Comment: buena alternativa, pero no nesecito comprimir o descomprimir url, nesecito es obtener la url final la que se muestra en la barra de navegacion despues de incluir la url, si analizas un poco, la url final integra tu ip, cuota y otros datos que identifical el acceso,y al cerrar tu navegador la url se vence y cada vez que accedes con la misma url inicial pues el resultado es distinto. no es comprimi ni descomprimir, gracias por la alternativa, pero solo busco obtener la url final en la barra de direcciones del popup despues de usar window.open o del src del video

Comment: @Manuelb lo que devuelve la `API` es lo que se me muestra en la ventana al hacer `window.open...` , no entiendo a que `url` se refiere entonces. Por cierto lo de las `IP` y demás datos tiene que ver con el contenido que está accediendo. si hace el proceso con otro dominio _(https://goo.gl/y8PRFo)_ verá el funcionamiento.

Comment: no digo que el uso de la api no sea malo, Por lo que he leido es una solucion practica, pero "yo no he podido" probarla ya que no entiendo o no se que he hecho mal ya que no se ejecuta. A pesar de lo mucho que he leido y de que he creado el proyecto y tengo la key, pero a pesar de eso no e podido obtener un resultado ni bueno ni malo, no se ejecuta, simplemente no se que hago mal, pero no tengo ningun resultado. Pero a pesar de eso, en todo lo que he leido es una gran solucion y a pesar que no me a funcionado, en donde e leido es una gran solucion, gracias.

Comment: Eso es un problema diferente. Le muestra algún mensaje de error en consola? `F12`, si es así ¿Cuál es? Así podré ayudar mucho mejor.

Comment: gracias por tu interes, pero en esta situacion no tengo ningun conocimiento y nesecitaria aprender desde 0, ya que no entiendo aunque mi conocimiento de js es basico en esto de los apis google no tengo ni idea. si me quieres orientar, estoy dispuesto y te lo agradeceria